# Python “expected an indented block” in Google Colab

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am completely new in python. I need help here please if somebody knows what is going on with my code?

```
app_reviews = []
for ap in tqdm(app_packages):
for score in list(range(1,6)):
for sort_order in [Sort.MOST_RELEVANT, Sort.NEWEST]:
rvs, _ = reviews(
ap,
lang='en',
country='us',
sort=sort_order,
count= 200 if score == 3 else 100,
filter_score_with=score
)
for r in rvs:
r['sortOrder'] = 'most_relevant' if sort_order == Sort.MOST_RELEVANT else 'newest'
r['appId'] = ap
app_reviews.extend(rvs)
```

the error appears

```
File "<ipython-input-33-c40fb4fad079>", line 3
    for score in list(range(1,6)):
      ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: check one of the answer posted. Did you indent the code properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to take care of your indentation, it's really important in python. Unlike other languages, when you get a condition block you need to tabulate once it is likes brackets.

```
app_reviews = []
for ap in tqdm(app_packages):
    for score in list(range(1,6)):
        for sort_order in [Sort.MOST_RELEVANT, Sort.NEWEST]:
            rvs, _ = reviews(
                ap,
                lang='en',
                country='us',
                sort=sort_order,
                count= 200 if score == 3 else 100,
                filter_score_with=score
            )
            
            for r in rvs:
                r['sortOrder'] = 'most_relevant' if sort_order == Sort.MOST_RELEVANT else 'newest'
                r['appId'] = ap
            app_reviews.extend(rvs)
```